# hightlight selection of d3.js element upon user input

Tags: jquery, css, html, d3.js

I have this code in the `jsfiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/L6u9x/4/

i also have a text input and a submit button. what i am trying to achieve is that when user enter a number shown in the svg boxes, that numbered box should get highlighted. But i know know how to do this.

```
var w = 100;

var h = 100;

var padding = 5;


var svg = d3.select('#svg1').append('svg')
.attr({
    width: w,
    height: h
});


svg.append('rect')
.attr({
    width: w,
    height: h,
    fill: 'red'
});


var little = svg.selectAll('rect.small')
.data(d3.range(9));


little.enter().append('rect')
.attr({
    width: w / 3 - padding * 2,
    height: h / 3 - padding * 2,
    fill: 'grey',
    x: function(d) { return d % 3 * (w / 3) + padding; },
    y: function(d) { return ~~(d / 3) * (h / 3) + padding; }
})




var text = svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(d3.range(9))
                    .enter()
                    .append("text");


//Add SVG Text Element Attributes

var textLabels = text
             .attr("x", function(d) { return d % 3 * (w / 3) + padding; })
             .attr("y", function(d) { return ~~(d / 3) * (h / 3)+ padding*5; })
             .text( function (d) { return d; })
             .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
             .attr("font-size", "20px")
             .attr("fill", "white");


$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

var val = $("input:first").val();



event.preventDefault();

var h = d3.select("rect").datum(val);

console.log(h);

});
```

Please help me out.

Comment: For starters you are doing a `d3.select("rect")` and asking if it has the value of your data. I'm pretty sure it won't know because you store the value in a text element?

Comment: So what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

This jsfiddle solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/L6u9x/5/

The key changes here are:

1. Add the `small` class to the `rect` which contain the numbers.

   ```
   little.enter().append('rect')
       .classed('small', true)
       .attr({
           width: w / 3 - padding * 2,
           height: h / 3 - padding * 2,
           fill: 'grey',
           x: function(d) { return d % 3 * (w / 3) + padding; },
           y: function(d) { return ~~(d / 3) * (h / 3) + padding; }
       })
   ```
2. `selectAll` the `rect.small` and then update the `fill` for the appropriate rect while resetting `highlight` for all other `rect.small`:

   ```
   d3.selectAll("rect.small").attr('fill', function (d) { return d === +val ? 'green' : 'grey'; });
   ```